# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: incomplete placeholder: '%(' without ')'

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pandas-to-sql

I have a few different functions that scrape different tables with pandas, saves each to a dataframe, and saves them to a PostgreSQL database. I am able to successfully scrape and save each table as a dataframe, but I am having a bit of an issue when saving it to SQL. I am trying to do this with something like the below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Opening sql connection
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:pw@localhost/name')
con = engine.connect()

def df1():
    df = scraped_data
    df.to_sql(table_name, con, if_exists='replace')
df1()

def df2():
    df = scraped_data
    df.to_sql(table_name, con, if_exists='replace')
df2()

# Closing connection
con.close()
```

I am able to successfully save `df1` to SQL, but I get an error when running `df2`.
**The only real difference  between the two functions is that they are scraping data from different sources.** Everything else is essentially the same.

I have a couple other functions for other dataframes, but only the first one ever works no matter which order I call the functions.

I keep getting the same error for all of the other functions I call:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: incomplete placeholder: '%(' without ')'
```

They also linked a page for background on the error: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405), although I still don't quite know what to make of it.

I just find it strange how it works for one function but not the others when the only thing that changes is the url that I am scraping from.

**EDIT**

I am scraping data from the NFL's website.

`df1` iterates through years in a table from http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?archive=false&conference=null&role=TM&offensiveStatisticCategory=GAME_STATS&defensiveStatisticCategory=null&season=2019&seasonType=REG&tabSeq=2&qualified=false&Submit=Go.

`df2` does a very similar thing but pulls data from http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?archive=false&conference=null&role=TM&offensiveStatisticCategory=TEAM_PASSING&defensiveStatisticCategory=null&season=2019&seasonType=REG&tabSeq=2&qualified=false&Submit=Go.

It looks like that the main difference is that `df1` uses `Pct` to represent percentage in a column header whereas `df2` uses `%`

Comment: i think it has to do with the con.close option. try and run it in such a way that both functions execute before getting to the con.close() line. or better, try it without the con.close and see if it writes successfully. if it does, then u can make adjustments for the connection clause

Comment: The second argument to `to_sql` needs to be `engine`, not `con`.

Comment: I tried both of the suggestions above but I am still getting the same error that I described in the post.

Comment: If the only difference is the data, then *please include a minimal sample of said data* in the question, or in other words produce a [mcve]. It usually also helps to include the *full traceback*, not just the error message. It would have included essential information in this case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You have a potential SQL injection hole.

The problem is that one of your column names contains `%`. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({"%A": ['x', 'y', 'z']})

In [9]: df.to_sql('foo', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

which produces the following log and traceback:

```
...
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
DROP TABLE foo
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
CREATE TABLE foo (
        index BIGINT, 
        "%%A" TEXT
)


INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INSERT INTO foo (index, "%%A") VALUES (%(index)s, %(%A)s)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:({'index': 0, '%A': 'x'}, {'index': 1, '%A': 'y'}, {'index': 2, '%A': 'z'})
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:ROLLBACK
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Work/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1239                     self.dialect.do_executemany(
-> 1240                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1241                     )

~/Work/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py in do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    854         if self.executemany_mode is EXECUTEMANY_DEFAULT:
--> 855             cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
    856             return

ProgrammingError: incomplete placeholder: '%(' without ')'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-88cf8a93ad8c> in <module>()
----> 1 df.to_sql('foo', engine, if_exists='replace')

...

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) incomplete placeholder: '%(' without ')'
[SQL: INSERT INTO foo (index, "%%A") VALUES (%(index)s, %(%A)s)]
[parameters: ({'index': 0, '%A': 'x'}, {'index': 1, '%A': 'y'}, {'index': 2, '%A': 'z'})]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

As can be seen SQLAlchemy/Pandas uses the column name as the placeholder key: `%(%A)s`. **This means that you may be open to SQL injection**, especially since you are handling scraped data:

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], """A)s);
   ...: DO $$
   ...: BEGIN
   ...: RAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';
   ...: END;$$ --""": ['x', 'y', 'z']})

In [4]: df.to_sql('foo', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

The result:

```
...
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO foo (index, "A", "A)s);
DO $$
BEGIN
RAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';
END;$$ --") VALUES (%(index)s, %(A)s, %(A)s);
DO $$
BEGIN
RAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';
END;$$ --)s)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ({'index': 0, 'A': 1, "A)s);\nDO $$\nBEGIN\nRAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';\nEND;$$ --": 'x'}, {'index': 1, 'A': 2, "A)s);\nDO $$\nBEGIN\nRAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';\nEND;$$ --": 'y'}, {'index': 2, 'A': 3, "A)s);\nDO $$\nBEGIN\nRAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';\nEND;$$ --": 'z'})
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RaiseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...

InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.RaiseException) HELLO, BOBBY!
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at RAISE

[SQL: INSERT INTO foo (index, "A", "A)s);
DO $$
BEGIN
RAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';
END;$$ --") VALUES (%(index)s, %(A)s, %(A)s);
DO $$
BEGIN
RAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';
END;$$ --)s)]
[parameters: ({'index': 0, 'A': 1, "A)s);\nDO $$\nBEGIN\nRAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';\nEND;$$ --": 'x'}, {'index': 1, 'A': 2, "A)s);\nDO $$\nBEGIN\nRAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';\nEND;$$ --": 'y'}, {'index': 2, 'A': 3, "A)s);\nDO $$\nBEGIN\nRAISE 'HELLO, BOBBY!';\nEND;$$ --": 'z'})]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
```

If you are using a database user with sufficient privileges, this allows for example executing arbitrary commands on your machine:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], """A)s);
    ...: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS evil (state text);
    ...: DO $$
    ...: BEGIN
    ...: IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM evil) THEN
    ...: COPY evil (state) FROM PROGRAM 'send_ssh_keys | echo done';
    ...: END IF;
    ...: END;$$ --""": ['x', 'y', 'z']})
```

This might seem like an oversight on SQLAlchemy's (and/or Pandas') part, but usually you are not meant to allow users, or outside data, to define your schema, and so table and column names are "trusted". **In this light the only proper solution is to whitelist columns**, i.e. check against a known set that your dataframe has only allowable columns.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I made an edit in my original post trying to explain the difference between `df1` and `df2`. It seems that a workaround to this issue would just be replacing the `%` symbol in `df2` to `Pct`.

Comment: It is a workaround for sure and you may want to remove or replace any `()` as well. I'm not a 100% sure if that'll close the hole, but at least it makes it quite a bit harder. Whitelisting and lookup replacements are safe.